# Using Sovryn api to borrow funds

Tags: ethers.js

```
import "./App.css";
```

import { ethers } from "ethers";
import contractJson from "./utils/contrat.json";
function App() {
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("https://mainnet.sovryn.app/rpc");
const signer = provider.getSigner();
const contract = new ethers.Contract(
"0x542FDA317318eBf1d3DeAF76E0B632741a7e677d",
contractJson,
signer
);
console.log(contract);
console.log("hi");

return (

## hii

);
}

export default App;

Using sovryn public rpc url but getting error :

Uncaught (in promise) Error: no such account
at JsonRpcProvider.getSigner (provider-jsonrpc.ts:1036:1)